# How to implement adaptive payment in paypal

Tags: php, paypal

I want to implement adaptive payment in my site. i am trying but getting an error
below is my code

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/js/external/dg.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webapps/adaptivepayment/flow/pay" target="PPDGFrame" class="standard">
<label for="buy">Buy Now:</label>
<input type="image" id="submitBtn" value="Pay with PayPal" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_paynowCC_LG.gif">
<input id="type" type="hidden" name="expType" value="light">
<input id="paykey" type="hidden" name="paykey" value="APP-80W284485P519543T">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
var embeddedPPFlow = new PAYPAL.apps.DGFlow({trigger: 'submitBtn'});
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

while i click on `Pay Now` button get the following error

[image]

Kindly let give me solution how to implement adaptive payment in paypal

Thanks Sanjib

Answer (score 1):

It's going to require more than basic HTML form posts.  You'll need to generate an API request (XML or JSON) and send it with some HTTP headers and a request body to the PayPal endpoint.  It would return a response that you would then parse accordingly.

Are you familiar with PHP?  You could use my [class library for PayPal](http://www.angelleye.com/download-angell-eye-php-class-library-for-paypal/) to make this easy on you.